# How to convert from byte[] to DoubleBuffer

Tags: java, buffer

doubleGeometryBuffer is a byte array that holds double values.

My question is how can I put doubleGeometryBuffer into a DoubleBuffer?

I have tried a suggestion of:

```
DoubleBuffer dbls = new ByteBuffer(doubleGeometryBuffer).asDoubleBuffer();
```

However this comes back with an error "Cannot instantiate the type ByteBuffer"

Comment: How come your byte[] holds double values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

`DoubleBuffer dbls = ByteBuffer.wrap(doubleGeometryBuffer).asDoubleBuffer();`

Comment: what if it needs to use direct?